# Zero'ing out deleted files

Tags: virtualization

I want to minimize the amount of space my virtual disk is using, by zero'ing out the data on any deleted files.  The virtual disk is a VDMK running ubuntu with a single Ext4 partition on VirtualBox.

What is the best way to find any deleted files, and zero them out, so that when I export the appliance the disk size is only existing files on the disk?

Comment: wait wha? if they are deleted why would they take up space?

Comment: @xenoterracide, When you are compressing or exporting a VM it does not look at the filesystem withing the guest.  It has no way to determine if a block is used, or not.  If you fill up all unused blocks with zeros within a guest then a VM will compress well.

Comment: After reading some answers and some comments. Your biggest problem appears to be how do you find said deleted files... I don't think the tools exist... esp not for ext4. I'd suggest rsync-ing the files you have to a new partition or image or something that won't have this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a filesystem that supports it then you can use [zerofree](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/zerofree).

If you are not then you basically need to just use dd to write zero to a file on each partition until there is no space left.  Then delete the file you filled with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

For each file system, do like

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/zero
# ...wait until the filesystem is full...
sudo rm /zero
```

That will create a file over all free space on the filesystem, filled with zeros. When you delete it, there will be only zeros left on partition. However, I guess you need to gzip the virtual disk anyway, as zeros take up space anyway. I am not sure how smart virtualbox disk management is.

Answer (score 1):

Dump and restore would work.

Comment: Dump and restore what exactly?

Comment: The `dump(1)` and `restore(1)` UNIX commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't deleted the files yet, you could do something like this:

```
shred --iterations=0 --exact --zero --remove file
```

Comment: The files have been deleted.  How could I find large deleted files to do shred against them?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you have to use thin provisioning. Or am i wrong there?